# Lottie Performance expo (react native)

Tags: react-native, expo, lottie

I’m having problems with the performance of a composition at the expo (react native), I tried to change the image to vector but I couldn’t solve the problem. Could someone help me with this problem?

https://lottiefiles.com/28372-world27

Comment: did you use react-native-lottie ?

Comment: Yes , i am using react-native-lottie

Answer (score 0):

There are known issues with Lottie working on expo, check the docs below
“ The Lottie SDK is currently considered to be under Expo's "DangerZone" because it's implementation is still in Alpha.
Importing Lottie 3 files causes the previewer to crash without a visible error, because Expo relies on lottie-react-native v2.”

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/lottie/